# Error trying to set css on typescript to devextreme component

Tags: css, angular, typescript, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I am using devextreme grid in my angular 5 app. When specific item is triggered the following code executes:

```
public setRowColor(e){
   e.rowElement.css("background-color","#d6dde7");
}
```

`rowElement` is one of the properties of row. I get the following error when this method executes:

> ERROR TypeError: e.rowElement.css is not a function

Comment: when this event is fired?

Comment: when (onRowPrepared) is triggere in dx-data-grid

Comment: which version of devextreme you are using `17.1` or `17.2`?

Comment: I am using devextreme 17.1.7

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is breaking change with the new version of devextreme, so I needed to add:

```
import 'devextreme/integration/jquery';
```

Comment: or use `e.rowElement.style.backgroundColor = '#d6dde7'`

Comment: Thanks a million times.This saved my day.